# 【ReactNative】How to execute display: "none" before rendering a screen

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I want to execute display: "none" before rendering a screen by few code changes.

Now `{goodbotton}` appears temporarily when the screen is renderd.

Currently my code is the below.

```
...
const [ goodbotton, setGoodBotton ] = useState(<Image source={require('../../images/good_botton_inactive.png')} style={ {width: 65, height: 65} }/>);

 <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        if (image.is_my_good) {
          postGood(image.id, false)
        } else {
          setGoodBotton(<Image source={require('../../images/good_botton.png')} style={ {width: 65, height: 65}}/>)
          postGood(image.id, true)
          setTimeout(() => {
            setGoodBotton(<Image source={require('../../images/good_botton_inactive.png')} style={ {width: 65, height: 65}}/>)
          }, 500)
        }
        }}>
        <View style={[image?.is_my_good ? styles.hide_good_botton : {}, commonStyles.shadow]} >
          {goodbotton}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
hide_good_botton: {
    display: "none"
  }
});
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way I've seen in projects is to have a state variable that controls when the application is fetching or processing something. Something similar to:

```js
    [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    // enter code here

    if (isLoading) { return (<View / Spinner / LoadingIcon / PlaceHolderView />) }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
             ....
```

Comment: thanks your comment!
I tried to adapt to my code.
But it  didn't works.
How can it works in my code?
I'm sorry,I'm beginner of react and javascript...